# Bimonads and internal categories

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a bimonad on a category C, with underlying functor B.  Can we find a bimonad that is also an internal category in [C,C], the category of endofunctors on C?

I have a specific reason for thinking this and it is described in [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282418/internal-category-in-an-endofunctor-category-possible-examples)

It comes down to finding a bimonad where the endofunctor preserves equalizers.

What if C is SET?  Can you find a bimonad on SET that preserves equalizers?

[Edit]
A bimonad is both a Monad and a comonad.

"There's a relationship between the monad structure and the comonad structure on B, or more exactly a mixed distributive law between them. In the terminology that some people use, this makes  into a "bimonad"."

-a quote I had on previous question

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a bimonad?

Comment: I don't understand how this could be an internal category. An internal category has two objects, and a nominal had only one.